# Why is a memory barrier necessary between MONITOR and MWAIT?

Tags: linux-kernel, thread-safety, memory-barriers, memory-fences

Perusing the [Linux x86 idle loop](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/acpi/cstate.c#L163), I noticed a memory barrier in between `monitor` and `mwait`, and I can't figure out exactly why it's necessary.

```
void mwait_idle_with_hints(unsigned long ax, unsigned long cx) {
    if (!need_resched()) {
        if (this_cpu_has(X86_FEATURE_CLFLUSH_MONITOR))   // True for Intel Xeon 7400 series CPUs
            clflush((void *)&current_thread_info()->flags);   // Workaround for erratum AAI65 for the Xeon 7400 series

        __monitor((void *)&current_thread_info()->flags, 0, 0);
        smp_mb();
        if (!need_resched())
            __mwait(ax, cx);
    }
}
```

`smp_mb()` is a macro for `asm volatile("mfence":::"memory")`.

Why is it necessary here? I understand why a compiler memory barrier would be necessary, but not a hardware memory barrier.

Comment: Isn't the memory barrier for `need_resched()`? Otherwise I'd assume it should go inside the `if` condition to not be executed if `mwait` isn't entered...?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yeah. I think I might understand it now. I think the second `need_resched` is needed in case `(void *)&current_thread_info()->flags` changes  between the first `need_resched` call and `monitor`. In order for the second `need_resched` call to actually check *after* `monitor` has been called, there needs to be a compiler and hardware memory barrier.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much the same thing I figured after exploring `need_resched` a bit more in depth.